# "enable_categorical=True" encoding method for xgboost library in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, xgboost

Let's assume `X_train` contains both numerical and categorical variables.

```
import xgboost as xgb

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data=X_train, label=y_train, enable_categorical=True)

params = {
    'objective': 'binary:logistic',  
    'max_depth': 10, 
    'learning_rate': 0.01,
    'eval_metric': 'logloss',  
    'subsample': 0.90, 
    'colsample_bytree': 0.90, 
    'min_child_weight': 10
}

model = xgb.train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round=1000)
```

How could I know which encoding method is used? Is it one among one-hot encoding, target encoding or label encoding? Or it is a smart selection?

Answer (score 0):

The feature is experimental and has limited features right now.

This seems to be a simple flag that lets to `xgboost` functions that your data have categorical feature and thus the function should use it.

The basic idea is create dataframe with category feature type, and tell XGBoost to use it by setting the enable_categorical parameter.

Have a look also at the source code:

- https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/093b6758380e4663d18729dd87d54a7845695a4b/python-package/xgboost/testing/__init__.py#L382
- https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/093b6758380e4663d18729dd87d54a7845695a4b/python-package/xgboost/core.py#L802

Source: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/categorical.html